# If statement is really slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made the following code in order to compare two columns between one and another, however it's taking more than a hour for the code to execute and sometimes it error out.

```
function testif() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss = sh.getSheetByName('test Data');
  const workingCell = ss.getRange(2,1).getValue()
  const today = ss.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  const Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  const Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  for(var i =2;i<=Alast;i++){

  const today30 = ss.getRange(i,3).getValue();

  if(workingCell >= today && workingCell <= today30){
    ss.getRange(i,4).setValue("Complaint");
  } else {
    ss.getRange(i,4).setValue("Non Complaint"); 
  }
  }
}
```

As you can see the code goes row by row and sees the if both of the conditions applies and insert data to the last column, I think that the issue is that the code is going row by row hence taking more then 1 hour to complete. Is there a way to fix this issue and make the code run faster?

For more clarity:

This is how the data looks originally:

| date to compare | today30 | today |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/9/2022 | 07/11/2022 | 08/10/2022 |
| 8/5/2022 | 07/11/2022 | 08/10/2022 |
| 7/29/2022 | 07/11/2022 | 08/10/2022 |
| 8/8/2022 | 07/11/2022 | 08/10/2022 |

And basically compare doing what the script does is and If(And)) between the columns, that goes as follow

```
=IF(AND($A2>=$B2,$A2<=$C2),"Compliant", "Non-Compliant")
```

Comment: you should try simple if formula with array formula that would be much faster than this and would be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.
- You want to convert a formula of `=IF(AND($A2>=$B2,$A2<=$C2),"Compliant", "Non-Compliant")` to Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `getValue` and `setValue` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function testif() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss = sh.getSheetByName('test Data');
  const values = ss.getRange("A2:C" + ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const res = values.map(([a, b, c]) => [a.getTime() >= b.getTime() && a.getTime() <= c.getTime() ? "Complaint" : "Non Complaint"]);
  ss.getRange(2, 4, res.length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: I edit the question for more clarity on the issue as the columns are named today and today30 are dates that are already made on the report.

Comment: @silentninja89 Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I updated my proposed script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: It does work, but what if the columns aren't located on A,B,C instead they are something like A,D,E?

Comment: nvm I found I found the way of doing by editing a couple of points in the code, Thanks a lot man

Comment: @silentninja89 Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.